# C# check if checkbox check(maybe user checked and unchecked a same checkbox)

Tags: c#

i have script from asp.net, which geting a value of checkBox, and may user click and unclick same checkbox, then i would to programm check 2 time if is check then delete it a selected row. the problem i have, when i check the checkbox and uncheck a same checkbox, i do not want to delete it, but it deletes, what i have to do with my code please?

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] Checked = hfLegalRecords.Value.Split('|');

    for (int i = 0; i < Checked.Length - 1; ++i)
    {
        string[] value = Checked[i].Split(',');
        string checkbox = value[0];
        string ClientCode = value[1];
        string DebtorNumber = value[2];
        if (checkbox.Equals("true"))
            for (int j = 0; j < checkbox[i]; ++j)
            {
                LegalEvents.RemoveSelectCheckBox(ClientCode, DebtorNumber);
            }
    }

    LoadLegalRecords();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are working with a grid/table.
Are you using javascript to track your CHECKs ? or each CHECK is a postback?

Use Onclick javascript function oo your checkBox and if user checks it. Update hfLegalRecords string with "ClientCode ,DebtorNumber , check" if he UNCHECK the same add "ClientCode ,DebtorNumber , uncheck" now when user clicks DELETE button

read the hfLegalRecords.Value.Split('|'); and store them in separate DataTables/Arrays (as if checked  move to Table 1; if unchecked move to Table2)

Assuming you dont have duplicate ClientCodes write a small code to check the count of records in both tables per ClientCode. If you have CientCode1 Checked . You have 1 entry tin Table 1. IF you have ClientCode2 Checked and Unchecked you have 1 entry in both Tables. If ClientCode3 is Checked, Unchecked and Checked you will have 2 entries in Table1 and 1 entry in Table2.

Either way, you logic should be "If entries in Table1 > entries in Table2 delete that ClientCode" else don't delete.

This will get complicated when you have more number records on the Screen with this simple structure of coding. I personally suggest to use Asp.Net grid controls. So you can get all records and verify the checked/unchecked when user click DELETE button. This will save lot of time and your effort in coding.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you're doing, but `checkbox[i]` is a string.

```
for (int j = 0; j < checkbox[i]; ++j)
{
    LegalEvents.RemoveSelectCheckBox(ClientCode, DebtorNumber);
}
```

<strike>Here you're just calling `LegalEvents.RemoveSelectCheckBox(ClientCode, DebtorNumber)` for each character in the string.</strike>

**Actually, this code won't even compile because of `j < "true"` is nonsense.**

Comment: i am trying if user check the checkbox then unchecked the same index of checkbox, do not delete it, but if user check the checkbox for the first time it is delete a row and if uncheck the same checbox which not to delete it, but it is delete it.